# Modification required in an existing SQL statement

Tags: sql-server, if-statement

I have the following SQL Query which displays the list of all the employees of a particular company based on ID of a single employee.

```
select TU.ApmId as 'ApmId', TU.UserId as 'PayRoll Id', 
       TU.UserName as 'Employee Name', P.ParLongDesc as 'Company Name'
from smart2uat.dbo.employee_mast TU, smart2uat.dbo.company_mast P 
where TU.ParID = P.PARID and TU.ParID = (select EM.ParId 
                                         from smart2uat.dbo.employee_mast EM   
                                         where EM.apmid='CBA134')
```

where `CBA134` is employee ID and `ParId` is a company ID.
I want a small modification in the code as:
If `ParID` of a given employee (employeeID) is `29` or `3` or `32` it have to display the combined employee details of all 3 companies else it have to display the employee details of a single company alone. Kindly help in code.

Sample data:

```
VDS007 VDS007 VERNE D'SOUZA    MS india Pvt. ltd - MUMBAI 
AJG004 AJG124 GAYATRI NIJASURE MS india Pvt. ltd - MUMBAI 
etc... etc....
```

(CBA134 Parid = 29 belongs to company MS india Pvt. ltd - MUMBAI)

Expected output:

```
VDS007 VDS007 VERNE D'SOUZA    MS india Pvt. ltd - MUMBAI 
AJG004 AJG124 GAYATRI NIJASURE MS india Pvt. ltd - MUMBAI 
KJG004 VJG124 ASHWIN NIJASURE  SAF india Pvt. ltd - MUMBAI 
AUG004 BJG124 ARUN GOPAL       GKR india Pvt. ltd - MUMBAI
etc....etc....
```

(CBA134 par id is 29 and hence i want employee details of company Par ID
 3,32,29 also) PARID 29 - MS india Pvt. ltd - MUMBAI , PARID 32 - SAF india Pvt. ltd - MUMBAI , PARID 3 - GKR india Pvt. ltd - MUMBAI

Comment: post some sample data and expected result

Comment: Sample data :

VDS007  VDS007   VERNE D'SOUZA      MS india Pvt. ltd - MUMBAI
AJG004   AJG124   GAYATRI NIJASURE  MS india Pvt. ltd - MUMBAI
............
.............
(CBA134 Parid = 29 belongs to company MS india Pvt. ltd - MUMBAI)

Expected output         
VDS007  VDS007   VERNE D'SOUZA      MS india Pvt. ltd - MUMBAI
AJG004   AJG124   GAYATRI NIJASURE  MS india Pvt. ltd - MUMBAI  
KJG004   VJG124   ASHWIN NIJASURE   SAF india Pvt. ltd - MUMBAI  
AUG004   BJG124   ARUN GOPAL          GKR india Pvt. ltd - MUMBAI

Comment: (CBA134 par id is 29 and hence i want employee details of company Par ID -3,32,29 also)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add sample data. That way, you can post tabular data and hit the `{}` button and we'll see tabular data. Even better would be to post the sample data as `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements so we can just copy & paste them to our own servers. But either way, please edit because sample data in comments is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

I've done it myself......thanks guys.....

```
declare @partemp int
select @partemp = ParId from smart2uat.dbo.employee_mast where apmid='CBA134'

if @partemp in (3,29,29)

begin
select TU.ApmId as 'ApmId', TU.UserId as 'PayRoll Id',TU.UserName as 'Employee Name',
P.ParLongDesc as 'Company Name'
from smart2uat.dbo.employee_mast TU, smart2uat.dbo.company_mast P where TU.ParID=P.PARID
and TU.ParID in (3,32,29) 
end

else 

begin
select TU.ApmId as 'ApmId', TU.UserId as 'PayRoll Id',TU.UserName as 'Employee Name',
P.ParLongDesc as 'Company Name'
from smart2uat.dbo.employee_mast TU, smart2uat.dbo.company_mast P where TU.ParID=P.PARID
and TU.ParID = @partemp
end
```